# Solve a non-linear system, in Python, with the GAUSS-NEWTON algorithm? (Jacobian matrix J, etc.)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data, numpy, scipy

I would like to solve a non-linear system (which contains the goals of a football team in previous matches) using the [Gauss-Netwon algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm), in order to find the parameter (**of frequency**) to use as lambda in the simple Poisson Distribution to calculate the probability of scoring a given number of goals. The question is not about Poisson, but only about the Gauss-Newton algorithm. I would need the executable solution as Python code, because with just a few suggestions i wouldn't be able to solve the problem. Is there any library that uses the Gauss-Newton algorithm or do you have to write everything manually? Can you show me how to solve the nonlinear system with Gauss-Newton with Poisson please?

I have a nonlinear system with three equations in a single unknown. The nonlinear system was created using the analytical expression of Poisson CDF with the [Distribution Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). I calculate the cumulative **frequencies** from the observations and use them as data. The system works properly, there are no problems. In the system are the goals of a football team in previous matches.

```
F(t) := P(X <= t) ~ sum_i_frequency(observation_i <=t) / total_observation =: f(t)

List_Goals: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
Matches played: 5

If the goals scored are <= 0 events, then i will have 0/5 = 0;
If the goals scored are <= 1 events, then I will have 2/5 = 0.4;
If the goals scored are <= 2 events, then I will have 5/5 = 1;

f(0) = 0/5 = 0;
f(1) = 2/5= 0.4;
f(2) = 5/5= 1;

System: {f(0) = F(0)} therefore 0/5 = 0;
        {f(1) = F(1)} therefore 2/5 = 0.4;
        {f(2) = F(2)} therefore 5/5 = 1;
```

The result of this system is: `0, 0.4, 1`

The system runs successfully with Python code:

```
import numpy as np
Goals = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2] 
probability_mass_function = np.bincount(Goals)/len(Goals)

cummulative_mass_function = probability_mass_function.cumsum()

print("probability_mass_function: ", probability_mass_function)
#result: ([0. , 0.4, 0.6])

print("cummulative_mass_function: ", cummulative_mass_function)
#result: ([0. , 0.4, 1. ])
```

### GAUSS-NEWTON

Now, i would like to solve the nonlinear system using the [Gauss-Netwon algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm), in order to find the parameter to use as lambda in the simple. Poisson distribution. So I would like to solve the nonlinear system using the following Gauss-Newton algorithm:
[image]

So what I would need is:

**a)** I identify the `Jacobian matrix J`, which in general is composed of the partial derivatives with respect to all the parameters. In this case I only have one parameter and the matrix is actually a column vector;

**b)** I calculate the transpose of `J` multiplied by `J`, which in this case is a scalar (formally a number, which however in this case is a function of the unknown parameter);

**c)** algorithmically speaking it looks good: the inverse of `J^T*J` is still a scalar, so I have to divide by that number (which however will contain the `mu` parameter);

**d)** I write the `iterative method` according to the formula and a stopping criterion;

So I get the parameter (**of frequency**)  to use in the Poisson distribution to calculate 0 goals, 1 goal, 2 goals, 3 goals, etc.
​
Naturally, these steps therefore, include functions and functional operators (the derivative). How can I use the Gauss-Network algorithm (with Python) on the non-linear system and get the final parameter I can use in Poisson distribution?

I would need the executable solution as Python code, because with just a few suggestions I wouldn't be able to solve the problem.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Python mathematical libraries `numpy` and `scipy` have routines for solving systems of linear equations: [`numpy.linalg.solve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) and [`scipy.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html#scipy.linalg.solve).

These are based on Gaussian elimination, rather than invertsing matrix (which can be achieved, e.g., by `numpy.linalg.inv`.)

See also [*Solving equations and inverting matrices*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.linalg.html#solving-equations-and-inverting-matrices) for the full list of available routines.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to warn you that I don't find your answer useful, because it doesn't answer what I'm looking for. As you have seen there is a Bounty +50. If you help me by editing your answer and writing a better one, I will be happy to give you the bounty. Thank you

Comment: FOR READERS: Of course I would also like to read solutions from other users :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

I am using scipy.optimize.least_squares method which implements Gauss-Newton method. (Doc - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html)

An example code I tried is below(Edited after clarification from comment)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from scipy.stats import poisson

# Define the Poisson distribution model
def poisson_model(params, x_data):
    # params: frequency parameter for the Poisson distribution
    return np.cumsum(poisson.pmf(x_data, params))

# Define the objective function
def objective_function(params, x_data, y_data):
    # x_data: the number of goals in previous matches
    # y_data: observed cumulative frequencies
    # Poisson distribution cumulative probabilities
    expected_cumulative_probabilities = poisson_model(params[0], x_data)
    # Compute the residuals
    residuals = expected_cumulative_probabilities - y_data
    return residuals

# Example data: number of goals in each match
goals_data = np.array([1, 2, 2, 1, 2])
max_goals = np.max(goals_data)
goal_counts = np.arange(0, max_goals + 1)
observed_cumulative_frequencies = np.cumsum(np.histogram(goals_data, bins=np.arange(-0.5, max_goals + 1.5))[0])

# Initial guess for the frequency parameter
initial_frequency = 1.0
initial_params = np.array([initial_frequency])

# Use least_squares to perform Gauss-Newton optimization
result = least_squares(objective_function, initial_params, args=(goal_counts, observed_cumulative_frequencies))

# The optimized frequency parameter is in result.x
optimized_frequency = result.x[0]

print("Optimized Frequency Parameter:", optimized_frequency)
```

In this code, observed_cumulative_frequencies represents the cumulative frequencies of goals. For example, if the observed cumulative frequencies for each goal count are [0, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5], it means that there are no occurrences of less than 0 goals, 1 occurrence of less than 1 goal, 3 occurrences of less than 2 goals, and so on.

Comment: What is observed_frequencies = np.array([0, 1, 3, 1, 0])? Why did you write 0, 1, 3, 1, 0? Can you explain to me with an example?

Comment: Looks like I didn't correct that, sorry,In your post, you have written goals as [1,2,2,1,2]. However you just need unique values so goals will be now [1,2] and then observed frequency will be [2,3] since 1 has a frequency of 2 and 2 has a frequency of 3

Comment: I'm not understanding. Where should I write my [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]?

Comment: Okay, you have your data as football goals. matches played : 5 and goals in those 5 matches are [1,2,2,1,2]. From this, you have to calculate frequency. In 5 matches, there were 2 matches in which goals scored were 1 and there were 3 matches in which goals scored were 2, so you goal data is now [1,2] and observed frequency is [2,3]. I hope this is clear. Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: There are two problems.You are counting differently than I would like. In my question I count differently.You counted 2 games in which 1 goal was scored, and then 3 games in which 2 goals were scored. As in my question, I would like to count 0 matches in which 0 or fewer goals were scored; 2 matches in which 1 or fewer goals were scored; 5 matches in which 2 or fewer goals were scored. Also, in your code, I don't have the possibility to DIRECTLY insert my List_Goals: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2].Could you fix your question a little and improve it please? I will be happy to deliver the bounty to you

Comment: I updated the code for using cumulative frequencies. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand why in your code there isn't a row in which to insert List_Goals: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]. I thought using the INPUT List_Goals: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2] was one of the most obvious, clear and simple things. You are using data and code, without the possibility of inserting the INPUT insert List_Goals: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150235/discussion-between-rathod-and-frimand).

Comment: I thought you already had code, since you calculated cumulatives at the beginning of your post. Updated to reflect your example

Comment: The only code I had was the one in the initial question with which I calculated [0. , 0.4, 1.]. Thanks you are kind. However, the code with the chat update prints the result 0.3780517578125. Instead the code in your answer prints me the result 0.529541015625. So there is a problem in your two code versions. What is the real result?

Comment: I AM NOT SURE OF THE QUALITY AND CORRECTNESS OF YOUR SOLUTION, MAYBE IT IS NOT CORRECT, I don't know, but I still want to reward you with the Bounty for the kindness and time spent
​